# React defaultValue for Select with Dynamically Generated Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, reactjs, redux

Use the defaultValue or value props on  instead of setting selected on .

```
<select defaultValue="react">
 <option value="react">React</option>
 <option value="angular">Angular</option>
</select>
```

defaultValue would work with the above select tag. However, it does not seem to work with options generated by loop.

```
<select defaultValue={selectedOptionId}>
{option_id.map(id =>
  <option key={id} value={id}>{options[id].name}</option>
)}
</select>
```

Probably options not fully been set when defaultValue was declared?

I could do manual assigning in `componentDidUpdate()` and `onChange` event.

But my question is - Is there any cleaner(better) way to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Any input on how you resolved this?

Answer (score 6):

This is old, but since answer #1 is related to a **controlled** `Select` and the question seems to be related to **uncontrolled** `Select` I think is worth to leave some lines for future readers:

The problem is that for `uncontrolled` components React needs to know what are the `options` **before the first render**, since from that moment the `defaultValue` won't override the current value of the `Select`. This means that if you render the `Select` before the `options` it won't know what to select.

You can solve the problem avoiding the `render` before the `options` are available:

```js
const RenderConditionally = ({ options, selected }) => options.length > 0 ? (
  <select defaultValue={selected}>
   {options.map(item => (
     <option key={item.id} value={item.value}>{item.label}</option>
   ))}
  </select>
) : null;
```

Or without ternary if you desire:

```js
const RenderConditionally = ({ options, selected }) => {
  if (options.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <select defaultValue={selected}>
      {options.map(item => (
        <option key={item.id} value={item.value}>{item.label}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think **first render** makes a difference. It should be whenever the component re-renders.

Answer (score 4):

For users running into this issue, you can get the desired functionality by using the `value` prop, instead of `defaultValue`, e.g.:

```
<select value={selectedOptionId}>
  {option_id.map(id =>
    <option key={id} value={id}>{options[id].name}</option>
  )}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have something wrong with `option_id` and `options` arrays structure, or `selectedOptionId` variable. The way you build your select component is ok.

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jhkcow8r/2/) where this code works fine:

```
render: function() {
let option_id = [0, 1];
let options = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}];
let selectedOptionId = 1
return (
  <select defaultValue={selectedOptionId}>
    {option_id.map(id =>
    <option key={id} value={id}>{options[id].name}</option>
    )}
  </select>
)
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I guess my problem was because those option values weren't there when the select component first initialised.
In my scenario, select component was mounted first then the data were pulled only when user click on particular link.
I updated the your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jhkcow8r/3/) to showcase my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I could find is to set `key` attribute the same as `defaultValue` so it will be a different element.

Aftermaths are not researched by me but I believe it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, React will complain because it uses **value** instead of **selected** for consistency across the form components, [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786669/warning-use-the-defaultvalue-or-value-props-on-select-instead-of-setting).

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
    const [states, setStates] = useState({
      selected: "Florida",
      values: [{name: "Alabama", code: "AL"}, {name: "Hawai", code: "HW"},{name: "Florida", code: "FL"}]
     });
  
    return (
       <select
      className="w-full"
      onChange={(e: any) => {
        setStates({
          ...states,
          selected: e.target.value,
        });
      }}
    >
      {states.values.map((state) => (
        <option
          value={state.name}
          key={state.name}
          selected={state.name === states.selected}
        >
          {state.name}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
    );
};


ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```