# Warning: Use the 'defaultValue' or 'value' props on <select> instead of setting 'selected' on <option>

Tags: reactjs, select, dropdown

**SCENARIO** A user has a dropdown and he selects an option. I want to display that dropdown and make that option a default value which was selected by that user last time.

I am using **selected** attribute on option but React generates a warning asking me to use default value on select.

For e.g.

```
render: function() {
    let option_id = [0, 1];
    let options = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}];
    let selectedOptionId = 0

    return (
      <select defaultValue={selectedOptionId}>
        {option_id.map(id =>
        <option key={id} value={id}>{options[id].name}</option>
        )}
      </select>
    )
  }
});
```

Problem is that I don't know the **selectedOptionId** as the selected option could be any option. How would I find the **defaultValue** ?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

React uses [`value` instead of `selected`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag) for consistency across the form components. You can use `defaultValue` to set an initial value. If you're [controlling the value](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), you should set `value` as well. If not, do not set `value` and instead handle the `onChange` event to react to user action.

**Note** that `value` and `defaultValue` should match the `value` of the option.

Comment: I used "value" attribute on select instead of defaultValue and as you said I kept the value of "value" attribute for option and select same. Thus, it worked..! Thanx.

Comment: if I use value to set seleted then I choose other option but select box not change value of option. :(

Comment: You have to set `value` on the SELECT element and it works!

Comment: We can use either value or defaultValue to set Initial value .

Comment: @Avan - setting `value` will set the initial value but will also require that you handle `onChange` to update the value. If you just want to set the initial value and let the component manage `value`, you must use `defaultValue`.

Comment: React docs have been changed, here is an updated link: https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#controlled-and-uncontrolled-components

Answer (score 135):

In an instance where you want to set a placeholder and not have a default value be selected, you can use this option.

```
      <select defaultValue={'DEFAULT'} >
        <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>Choose a salutation ...</option>
        <option value="1">Mr</option>
        <option value="2">Mrs</option>
        <option value="3">Ms</option>
        <option value="4">Miss</option>
        <option value="5">Dr</option>
      </select>
```

Here the user is forced to pick an option!

**EDIT**

> If this is a controlled component

In this case unfortunately you will have to use both defaultValue and value violating React a bit. This is because react by semantics does not allow setting a disabled value as active.

```
 function TheSelectComponent(props){
     let currentValue = props.curentValue || "DEFAULT";
     return(
      <select value={currentValue} defaultValue={'DEFAULT'} onChange={props.onChange}>
        <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>Choose a salutation ...</option>
        <option value="1">Mr</option>
        <option value="2">Mrs</option>
        <option value="3">Ms</option>
        <option value="4">Miss</option>
        <option value="5">Dr</option>
      </select>
    )
}
```

Comment: Be careful, since your default option `<option value="DEFAULT" disabled>Choose a salutation ...</option>` has a truthy value, if this select input is marked as required it won't be caught by default form validation. Consider using an empty string instead `""`.

Comment: User don't necessary have to use both. You can use a disabled option as an active placeholder if you set its value to a non-truthy value i.e ""  & pass that value as either defaultValue or value to select.

Comment: Wouldnt it be better UX wise if the default value is marked as `hidden` instead of `disabled`?

Answer (score 14):

What you could do is have the `selected` attribute on the `<select>` tag be an attribute of `this.state` that you set in the constructor. That way, the initial value you set (the default) and when the dropdown changes you need to change your state.

```
constructor(){
  this.state = {
    selectedId: selectedOptionId
  }
}

dropdownChanged(e){
  this.setState({selectedId: e.target.value});
}

render(){
  return(
    <select value={this.selectedId} onChange={this.dropdownChanged.bind(this)}>
      {option_id.map(id =>
        <option key={id} value={id}>{options[id].name}</option>
      )}
    </select>
  );
}
```

Comment: use "defaultValue" instead of the "selected" attribute

Answer (score 7):

Thank you all for this thread!  My colleague and I just discovered that the `default_value` property is a Constant, not a Variable.

In other React forms I've built, the default value for a Select was preset in an associated Context.  So the first time the Select was rendered, `default_value` was set to the correct value.

But in my latest React form (a small modal), I'm passing the values for the form as props and then using a `useEffect` to populate the associated Context.  So the FIRST time the Select is rendered, `default_value` is set to `null`.  Then when the Context is populated and the Select is supposed to be re-rendered, `default_value` cannot be changed and thus the initial default value is not set.

The solution was ultimately simple: Use the `value` property instead.  But figuring out why `default_value` didn't work like it did with my other forms took some time.

I'm posting this to help others in the community.

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue, could you provide an example of this issue, I've tried with value, but for me the problem remains.

Answer (score 7):

Use defaultValue and onChange like this

```
const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState('');

<select onChange={(e) => setMyValue(e.target.value)} defaultValue={props.myprop}>
                    
       <option>Option 1</option>
       <option>Option 2</option>
       <option>Option 3</option>

</select>
```

Example
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-lamarr-fetpr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Would't you need `value` on the `option`s too to get `e.target.value`?

Comment: @CodeFinity, No, it's not required. You can take a look here https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-lamarr-fetpr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @CodeInfinity, It's not required because the onChange in the select tag is meant to track the options

Answer (score 2):

#### With Hooks and `useState`

Use `defaultValue` to select the default value.

```
    const statusOptions = [
        { value: 1, label: 'Publish' },
        { value: 0, label: 'Unpublish' }
    ];
    const [statusValue, setStatusValue] = useState('');
    const handleStatusChange = e => {
        setStatusValue(e.value);
    }

return(
<>
<Select options={statusOptions} 
    defaultValue={[{ value: published, label: published == 1 ? 'Publish' : 'Unpublish' }]} 
    onChange={handleStatusChange} 
    value={statusOptions.find(obj => obj.value === statusValue)} required />
</>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to set the value without using selected in option,

follow these steps:

Default the value to 0 [which I am not considering it as a value to be in use] to **x-column**

Refer the image[image]

4 steps

1. set the "IntialValue" of the **x-column** **: 0** to the
2. use the same string used in your [***selected***] and set it here with the if condition and when found, mark the "**values.x-column = 0**"
3. Remove the "selected" and other items set [if any] in  tag
   4.finally set this condition

now navigate , the value in the column is defaulted to the one which is marked in step-2 / that you wanted to be set in selected

I have tried and its working for me

A small correction.. line 45 in image.. read the column as *column_value_id*

Answer (score 0):

I tried different options to avoid console errors the following option worked with selected option without errors in console:

```
    {const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState('');  
  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    setMyValue(e.target.value);
  };
<select id="select" value={myValue} onChange={changeHandler}>
            {!myValue&& <option value="">choise from list</option>}
            {elementsArr.map((el) => {
              return (
                <option key={el.id} value={el.name}>
                  {el.name}</option>
              );
            })
          </select>}
```

Answer (score 0):

From options, you should be **instead** of **value** to **defaultValue** from options of that select:->

```js
<select className="form-control text-align:center" onChange={handleChangeCountry}>
            <option type="others" >Select a Country</option>
            {users?.length > 0 && users.map(item => {
              return (<option selected={item.country_name === countryName} key={item.country_id} defaultValue={item.country_id} >
                {item.country_name}
              </option>)
            })}
          </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

use defaultValue as suggested above
<select

```
          <option>Please select</option>
          {categories.length > 0 &&
            categories.map((c) => (
              <option
                key={c._id}
                defaultValue={c._id}
                selected={c._id === parent}>
                {c.name}
              </option>
            ))}
        </select>
```