# Select box in reactjs shows me warning as " Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<select>
{items.map((item, index) => {
return (
<option value={item.id} key={index}>{}</option>  
)       
})}
</select>
```

Select box in reactjs shows me warning as

> Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on `<select>` instead
>   of setting `selected` on `<option>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: Use the 'defaultValue' or 'value' props on <select> instead of setting 'selected' on <option>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786669/warning-use-the-defaultvalue-or-value-props-on-select-instead-of-setting)

Comment: @SaranshKataria ....Can you explain me clearly..Its not understandable to me