# Don't use selected Error using Material UI select component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am getting an error:

> Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on  instead
> of setting `selected` on .

```js
<Select
  onChange={props.changecompany}
  value={props.currCompany != undefined ? props.currCompany.id : -1}
>
  <option key={'empty'} value={'-1'}>
    None
  </option>
  {mapstructure()}
</Select>;
```

And here is my `mapstructure()`

```js
const mapstructure = () => {
  return companies.map((company) => (
    <option key={company.Id.toString()} value={company.Id}>
      {company.Name}
    </option>
  ));
};
```

I'm still learning so it is probably something fairly obvious, but the google solutions havent seemed to have fixed it.  TIA

Comment: See if this can help: [Warning: Use the 'defaultValue' or 'value' props on <select> instead of setting 'selected' on <option>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786669/warning-use-the-defaultvalue-or-value-props-on-select-instead-of-setting)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't.   I have tried -1 as the defaultValue as well and it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think:

React throws a warning (not error) because, Material UI is using `selected` instead of `value`.
You have done nothing wrong and should not worry about it.
This can be fixed by Material UI itself in the upcoming updates if you raise this issue.

I hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: I have marked as accepted, and believe you are right unless someone else has some reason otherwise.   It does behave as expected, I just received that error.